# Use optional to check Null pointer exception

Tags: java, optional

I currently have something like this:

```
Price price = new Price();
ActualValue actualValue = new ActualValue();
actualValue.setValue(price.getPreviousPrice().getRegion().getValue());
```

I want to make sure when calling `getRegion()` and `getValue()`, no NPE is thrown, trying to make it write in one line so I thought about using `Optional`

Currently what I have is this:

```
Optional.of(price)
            .flatMap(d -> Optional.ofNullable(d.getPreviousPrice())
            .flatMap(p -> Optional.ofNullable(p.getRegion())
                    .flatMap(m -> Optional.ofNullable(m.getValue()))))
            .ifPresent(v -> actualValue.setValue(v));
```

Looks ugly, how can I improve?

Answer (score 7):

[Optional.map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) produces a cleaner code. It's similar to flatMap except the function inside doesn't need to know about Optional. Also passing [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) makes things a little bit shorter.

```
Optional.of(price)
        .map(Price::getPreviousPrice)
        .map(Price::getRegion)
        .map(Region::getValue)
        .ifPresent(ActualValue::setValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to make rare use of the Optional-construct. It may make the code look "cleaner" and surly "shorter" but it brings a false sense of safety. BTW less code is no metric to follow.

I would come from the other side and ask questions like:

1. Do I violate the law of demeter with "price.getPreviousPrice().getRegion().getValue()"?
2. Why should a previous price have no region where it is valid?

You should have a look at your design. These new constructs may have their applications. But most of the time I see them in usage they hide design flaws. Semantical problems where obfuscated by language mechanisms.